# Javascript play mp3 from random number

Tags: javascript, random, mp3

Here's what I'm after:

On page load - play an mp3 chosen after running a script for a random number (not list) and adding the ".mp3" to it...

This is what I got so far and it's not working:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 
function myFunction() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
  }   
    
document.write ('<audio src= "media/' + x + '.mp3" controls autoplay></audio>')

</script>
```

Please help. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `src` attribute of the `audio` element, not to add another element each time.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    document.getElementById("myAudio").src = "media/" + x + ".mp3";
}
```

```html
<body onload="myFunction();">
    <audio id="myAudio" src="" controls autoplay></audio>
</body>
```

Note that you can call `myFunction();` anytime to change *randomly* the current mp3.

Comment: pistou, you solved it so fast.. you're awesome. thanks a lot!

Comment: @Ben.Cohen You're welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer so people with the same issue can see it.